# How should I join these tables MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables:

Report:

```
id, ip_addr, upload_id
```

Upload:

```
id, userID, name, location, category, private
```

Basically I am displaying all the uploads and I want to join the report table to determine if the current user's ip_address has reported the upload (I will compare ip_addr after query). The problem I am running into is that there can be multiple reports for the same upload, and by different people (not necessarily a registered user, which is why I am using the ip_addr). So how would I setup this MySQL query and how can I perform the following while in a loop..?

PHP: ($things would be the query result)

```
foreach((array)$things as $files){
    if ($files['ip_addr'] == $user_ip_addr) {
         // display upload info and an already reported image
    } else {
         // display upload info with an unreported image
    }
}
```

So far I have this, which display all the uploads

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM upload WHERE private="0" ';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have multiple identifiers.
table structure would be similar to this:

Table 'reports'

```
reported_by = user id 
reported_id = upload id
id = primary index
```

Your query could be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `rows` WHERE reported_id = ? AND reported_by = ?
```

Et voila,

```
<?php
    if($rows['rows'] > 0) // they reported it
        echo 'Tattle tale.';
    else
        echo 'Snitches get stitches.';
?>
```

? are unnamed parameters (assuming you're using mysqli or pdo)

Comment: I record an ip_address not a user id in the report table, because it doesn't have to be a registered user that reports. I'm not sure that you understood what I was asking...

Comment: How would the JOIN query look? I notice you do a count, but the count is merely to show the total number of reports of a given upload id. If the ip_addr has a match with an upload_id then I will display a flag that means you already reported the upload.

Comment: Why do you need to use the JOIN keyword at all?
This will select ALL the reports where the IP that REPORTED the upload is THEIR IP.

Comment: I don't want to select all the reports..I want to select all the uploads and then check to see if the current user has reported any given upload.

Comment: Then don't single out one upload ID.

SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reporter_ip = ?